# Am new to cucumber. I am running two feature files. While running it shows an error. If am running the first tag only it runs fine

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, cucumber-java

```
@CucumberOptions(features = { "src\\test\\java\\com\\Features\\" }, glue = { "stepDefinitions" }, plugin = {
    "pretty", "json:target/cucumber.json" }, tags = { "@Login","@baseCheck"}, monochrome = true)
```

Please help me solve this issue.

```
Error : None of the features at [src\test\java\com\Features\] matched the filters: [@Login, @baseCheck]
```

Comment: Could you share your feature files as well?

Comment: @Mahipal..I have placed the tags with in a double quotes separating with a comma. Issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this scenario Runner checks for feature which contains two tags "Login" and "baseCheck", however in your case one feature file contains tag as "Login" and other feature file contains tag as "baseCheck". Hence it treats as no feature exist with two tags and shows error as 'No feature' exist.

One quick fix is you have to add tags in testrunner as tags= {"@login,@basecheck"}

Comment: fixed. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

you specified each tag name in double quote, try this tag={ "@Login,@baseCheck"}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, We need to define  Cucumber setting as below.
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resources"}, 
        glue={"classpath:gradle/cucumber"},
        format= {"pretty","html:test-outout"},
        tags = {"@SmokeTests,@RegressionTest"}          
        )

public class TestRunner {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also used tags like this = { "@Login","@baseCheck"},

just write @baseCheck below Feature: and above Scenario: otherwise it will take tag as feature and throw exception "None of the features at [src\test\java\com\Features] matched the filters: [@Login, @baseCheck]"

For example:-

Feature: My Feature File

@baseCheck

Scenario: My scenerio

Given first

Then second

Then Third